# Lipschitz in $\mathbb R^1$ implies Lipschitz along any line in $\mathbb R^k$ (for convex functions)

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

I'm trying to solve a homework problem (baby rudin course) and realized that Lipschitz continuity really makes the problem easier for me. However, since it is not defined in Rudin I have to prove the properties if I want to use them.

I have just argued that convex functions are (locally) lipschitz in $\mathbb R^1$. I'm trying to avoid arguing that it holds in $\mathbb R^k$ directly since the proof is messy and too difficult. However, I really need it to apply to any line in $\mathbb R^k$. I wrote:

"ii) Convex functions are locally Lipschitz along any line in $\mathbb R^n$.

Let $f$ be defined on some set $C \in R^n$ let $I=\{u| a< u<b\} \subset K$ be a line with $a<s<t<u<b$. We have assumed without loss of generality that the line is a linear combination of $e_1$. This is further justified in c) but really it is just a matter of notation in this case. Then by convexity (c.f. excercise R4.23)
$$\frac{f(t)-f(s)}{t-s}\leq \frac{f(u)-f(s)}{u-s}\leq \frac{f(u)-f(t)}{u-t}$$
Now choose
$$K=\max\left[\left|\frac{f(t)-f(s)}{t-s}\right|,\left|\frac{f(u)-f(t)}{u-t}\right|\right]$$
It follows that
$$  \frac{\left|f(u)-f(s)\right|}{\left|u-s\right|}\leq K \rightarrow |f(u)-f(s)|\leq K|u-s|$$
And thus $f$ is locally Lipschitz on $I$ and we have the result desired."

I feel that my argument that it applies to $\mathbb R^k$ is not very strong at the moment. I was considering induction, but I'm unsure what to induct on really.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
I think I solved it:
For $\mathbb R^n$ consider the function $f$ restricted to any line $I \in R^n$, this can be considered a convex function on a subset of $\mathbb R^1$, and then the result follows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> For $\mathbb R^n$ consider the function $f$ restricted to any line $I\in \mathbb R^n$, this can be considered a convex function on a subset of $\mathbb R^1$, and then the result follows.

You should be more careful. It is true that convexity is *determined by line restrictions*, i.e., a function $f:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R$ is convex if and only if its restriction to every line is. But for the Lipschitz condition this is **false** unless we have uniform control on Lipschitz constant. The problem is that a function may be Lipschitz on every line, but with a constant depending on the line; since there are infinitely many lines to consider, we might not be able to pick a Lipschitz constant that works for all of them, even locally. This is not just an abstract concern: the function 
$$f(x,y) = \frac{xy^2}{x^2+y^4},\qquad f(0,0)=0$$ 
is locally Lipschitz on every line, but is not continuous at $(0,0)$.

You can still fix the argument by making the one-dimensional version *quantitative*. That is, show that if $f:\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ is convex, then it is Lipschitz on $[-a,a]$ with a constant that depends only on $a$ and $\sup_{[-2a,2a]} |f|$. (It is  important to have the larger interval in the supremum.) The proof goes like this: if some secant of $f$ on $[-a,a]$ has a large slope, then it grows large either at $2a$ or at $-2a$, and $f$ will be even bigger there.

With this quantitative version, the argument by line restriction works. Let $M$ be the supremum of $|f|$ on a ball of radius $2R$ cantered at the origin. Consider the restriction of $f$ to the ball of radius $R$ centered at the origin: this restriction will be Lipschitz on every line, with a uniformly bounded constant, independent of line.