# Let $X$ be a separable Banach space. Then every pointwise bounded $(f_n) \subset X^*$ has a subsequence that converges uniformly on compact sets

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, banach-spaces, weak-convergence, weak-topology

This thread is meant to record a question that I feel interesting during my self-study. I'm very happy to receive your suggestion and comments.

See: [SE blog: Answer own Question](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/) and [MSE meta: Answer own Question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/4680/79762).

---

In Brezis's *Functional Analysis*, there is a corollary

> **Corollary 3.30.** Let $E$ be a separable Banach space and let $\left(f_{n}\right)$ be a bounded sequence in $E^*$. Then there exists a subsequence $\left(f_{n_{k}}\right)$ that converges in the weak topology $\sigma\left(E^*, E\right)$.

It seems the corollary still holds for a general (*not necessarily complete*) normed space, i.e.,

> Let $E$ be a separable **normed space** and let $\left(f_{n}\right)$ be a **bounded** sequence in $E^*$. Then there exists a subsequence $\left(f_{n_{k}}\right)$ that converges in the weak topology $\sigma(E^*, E)$.

Recently, I have come across a theorem which requires less from $(f_n)$ and gives stronger result if $E$ is a Banach space.

- **Theorem 1:**  Let $X$ be a **Banach space**, and $(f_n) \subset X^{*}$ a sequence that converges pointwise on $X$ to a (linear) functional $\ell: X \to \mathbb{R}$. Then $(f_n)$ is bounded, $\ell \in X^{*}$, and the convergence is [uniform on compact sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_convergence).
- **Theorem 2:** Let $E$ be a **separable Banach space** and let $\left(f_{n}\right)$ be a **pointwise bounded** sequence in $E^*$, i.e., the set $\{f_n(x) \mid n \in \mathbb N\}$ is bounded for each $x\in X$. Then there exists a subsequence $\left(f_{n_{k}}\right)$ that converges in the weak  topology $\sigma(E^*, E)$ and [uniformly on compact sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_convergence)s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd like to share a few related facts that you may find useful. You can easily find the proofs in the functional analysis books.

> *Proposition:* Let $K$ be compact and $S=\{g_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}\subseteq C(K)$ be an equicontinuous set of functions. If $g_n\to g_0$ pointwise, then $g_n\to g$ uniformly on $K$.
>
> *Proof:* By the Ascoli-Arzela theorem, $S$ is relatively compact in $(C(K),\|\cdot\|_\infty)$. If $g_n\not\to g_0$ uniformly on $K$, then there existed a subsequence $(g_{n_j})$ and a $h\in C(K)\backslash\{g_0\}$ such that $g_{n_j}\to h$ uniformly. But this contradicts the fact that $g_n\to g_0$ pointwise.

For Theorem 1, suppose $f_n\to f_0$ in $\sigma(X^*,X)$ topology and $K\subseteq X$ be compact. As you observed, $(f_n)$ is bounded, say by $c>0$. Let $g_n = f_n|_K$ be the restrictions to $K$. For every $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $x,y\in K$
$$|g_n(x)-g_n(y)| = |f_n(x-y)|\leq c\|x-y\|$$
Thus, $S=\{g_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}\in C(K)$ is an equicontinuous set of functions. At this point, we can use the Proposition above.

Theorem 2 can be paraphrased as: If $X$ is separable, then any weak$^{*}$ closed and bounded subset $D\subseteq X^{*}$ is weak$^{*}$ sequentially compact. Compactness is by the Banach-Alaoglu theorem, and sequential compactness is due to the fact that $\sigma(X^*,X)$ topology on $D$ is metrizable if $X$ is separable. More generally, if $X$ is weakly compactly generated, then the dual unit ball of $X^*$ is weak$^*$ sequentially compact (e.g., see https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1246535/922380).

Answer (score 0):

Let's prove **Theorem 1**. Clearly, $(f_n)$ is bounded by [Banach-Steinhaus theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4459741/a-proof-of-banach-steinhaus-theorem-via-convex-analysis). The rest follows from below *Lemma 1*.

- [*Lemma 1:*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4457958/how-to-prove-that-the-convergence-of-f-n-is-uniform-on-compact-sets) Let $C$ be an open convex subset of a **Banach space** $X$. Let $(f_{n})$ be a sequence of lower semi-continuous convex functions on $C$ that converges pointwise on $C$ to a (convex) function $f: C \to \mathbb{R}$. Then $f$ is continuous and the convergence is [uniform on compact sets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_convergence#Definition).

Let's prove **Theorem 2**. Notice that $f_n \to f$ in $\sigma(E^*, E)$ if and only if $f_n  \to f$ pointwise. The result then follows from below *Lemma 2*.

- [*Lemma 2:*](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4459438/let-f-n-be-a-pointwise-bounded-sequence-of-l-s-c-convex-functions-then-f) Let $C$ be an open convex subset of a **separable Banach space** $X$. Let $(f_n)$ be a pointwise bounded sequence of l.s.c. convex functions on $C$. Then there exists a subsequence $(f_{\varphi(n)})$ of $(f_n)$ that converges pointwise and [uniformly on compact subsets](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compact_convergence#Definition) to a continuous convex function on $C$.